# Is it possible to use multi path symbols in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I know you can add your own symbols to highcharts like this:

```
$.extend(Highcharts.Renderer.prototype.symbols, {
      up: function() {return "m 100 100 l 300 100 l 200 300 z"}
```

I am unclear if you can do this with a multi-path symbol for example a rectangle with an arrow over top.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is use a different symbol, and don't mind using an image, you can use [a marker](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#point-marker) instead.